# Is it possible to change the the safeAreaInsets to a custom value?

Tags: swiftui

I have a customized Tabbar in my application that is a little big taller than the native/default iOS Tabbar. Therefore my customized Tabbar covers the content area a little bit. Is there a way to change the `safeAreaInsets` or do I have to add a padding manually on each view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information `safeAreaInsets` are **get** only, if there is value for them you can get, otherwise you can **NOT** set value to that.

**A good tip:** you should always be aware of your content size, that means, what we should do if the content size get bigger than safe area? and you can find lots of way for that, for example using ScrollView or padding . . .

Comment: Is this an answer that solves the problem?

Comment: @Rob: yes, safeAreaInsets is get only! not changeable as I answered! What could be more helpful than my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In UIKit there is a `additionalSafeAreaInsets` property on `UIViewController` you can modify to get larger `safeAreaInsets`. Wrapping everything in a View Controller/Hosting Controller might propagate this to your SwiftUI Views.